# Flutter - Pull to refresh with RefreshIndicator in FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, networking, futuretask

Edit: [Minimal reproducible example](https://github.com/klasenma/futurebuilder_with_refresh). Please have a look at the refresh-Method in `main.dart`.

I'm using a `FutureBuilder` to display the result of a network request. I call my fetch method in `initstate` (like suggested [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#4-fetch-the-data)):

```
Future<List<CheckIn>> futureCheckIn;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _eventArg = Provider.of<EventArg>(context, listen: false);

  _helper = ApiHelper(context);
  futureCheckIn = _helper.fetchCheckIns(_eventArg.getEvent().id.toString());
}
```

I now want to use a `RefreshIndicator` to allow the user to refresh the screen.
This works great until my network request ends with an exception (e.g. 404). Normally the exception get caught by the `FutureBuilder` but after excecution the request in the `RefreshIndicator` the exception is unhandled...

Here my code:

```
RefreshIndicator buildResult(List<CheckIn> checkIns, BuildContext context) {
return RefreshIndicator(
  key: _refreshKey,
  onRefresh: () async {
    setState(() {});
    futureCheckIn =
        _helper.fetchCheckIns(_eventArg.getEvent().id.toString()); // this could end with an exception
  },
  child: Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Text(
              constants.CHECK_IN_SCREEN_DESCRIPTION,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
            ),
          ),
          ListView(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: checkIns.map((el) {
              return Card(
                elevation: 4,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(el.name),
                  onTap: () async {
                   ...
                  },
                  trailing: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

**How can I use the `RefreshIndicator` properly with `FutureBuilder`?**

Edit @Shri Hari: This exception is thrown

```
class AppException implements Exception {
 final _message;
 final _prefix;

 AppException([this._message, this._prefix]);

 String toString() {
   return "$_prefix$_message";
 }
}

class NotFoundException extends AppException {
  NotFoundException([String message]) : super(message, "Data not found: ");
}
```

[image]

Edit @Mhark Batoctoy: Yes it is part of the `FutureBuilder`:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return FutureBuilder(
  future: futureCheckIn,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      List<CheckIn> checkIns = snapshot.data;

      return buildResult(checkIns, context); // RefreshIndicator is nested in here
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      // Error handling
      ... 
    }

    // Spinner während der Datenabfrage
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  },
);
```

Unfortunatelly changing the `onRefresh`-Method from

```
 onRefresh: () async {
  setState(() {});
  futureCheckIn =
    _helper.fetchCheckIns(_eventArg.getEvent().id.toString()); // this could end with an exception
  },
```

to

```
onRefresh: () async {
  setState(() {});
  return futureCheckIn =
    _helper.fetchCheckIns(_eventArg.getEvent().id.toString()); // this could end with an exception
  },
```

or

```
onRefresh: () async {
  setState(() {});
  return _helper.fetchCheckIns(_eventArg.getEvent().id.toString()); // this could end with an exception
  },
```

does not change the error...

Comment: Can you post the exception?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the best answer but I faced same problem and have to move ahead. So, this is what I learned and did.

`RefreshIndicator` don't like exception. That is even after moving them under `try / catch` or `onError` and consume exception successfully, `RefreshIndicator` still cries for unhandled exception (bit weird but I will have to investigate it more).

What I did was to make sure my API call don't throw any exception. That means, the API call itself (in this case `fetchCheckIns()` function call) catches all types of known / unknown exceptions [ `catch (e)` ] and set a flag in your response object that you are returning from the API (in this case the return type object of `fetchCheckIns()`).

Now, in your `FutureBuilder`, when you are calling `buildResult(checkIns, context)`, check for `snapshot.data` and look for any failure flag. If you get failure, render the screen differently. That is:

```
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      if (snapshot.data.error == true) {
         return ...; // Render error message
      } else {
         return buildResult(snapshot.data, context);
      }
    }
```

This also means, you may not be able to return List of objects and may have to wrap that in a single object which will contain list of objects.

Means, your `CheckIn` object may be wrapped with something like

```
class AllCheckIn {
   List<CheckIn> checkIns;
   bool error;
   String errorMsg;
}
```

Optionally, you can also add more description of error message based on your exception that you have received and captured in your API call and use that in your `FutureBuilder`.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Yeah I thought that too and couldn't found any example that managed to handle the exceptions. Your approach sounds interesting. I'll use it the next time I'll need a RefreshIndicator. I'll give you feedback then. For now +1 and thanks for your reply @Virendra.

Answer (score 0):

```
 _helper.fetchCheckIns(_eventArg.getEvent().id.toString());
```

It returns a Future. Either a `data` that you need or an `error`. You can use the `async await` inside the `try catch finally` block or you can use `Future.then() / Future.catchError / Future.whenComplete()`.

Example:

```
onRefresh: () async {
try {
   //You can use the await keyword here.
   return futureCheckIn =
    await _helper.fetchCheckIns(_eventArg.getEvent().id.toString());
}catch (err){
  //You can display the error here using a snackbar.
  }finally {
    //This executes whether there is an error or not. 
 }
```

},

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already tried using `await`, but as `futureCheckIn` is from type `Future<List<CheckIn>>` it doesn't work because `await _helper.fetchCheckIns(_eventArg.getEvent().id.toString());` is from type `List<CheckIn>`...

Comment: Is your RefreshIndicator inside FutureBuilder? If so, try returning the _helper.fetchCheckIns() in your onRefresh()

Comment: can you try putting your futureCheckIn inside the setState()?

Comment: Unfortunately the exception still occures.. I will try to write a minimal reproducible example in the next day.

Comment: Ok. Try putting the futureCheckIn = _helper.... inside the try catch block.

Comment: I added a minimal reproducible example: https://github.com/klasenma/futurebuilder_with_refresh.